# The Command CreateProcess C++

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess, waitforsingleobject

The Command CreateProcess With the command WaitForSingleObject
can to open an image?
If Yes How can I open the image?
I tried to open but i don't know Where to put the path to open

```
    if (CreateProcess(NULL, "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Paint.lnk", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
```

Comment: There are many thousand of examples all over the Internet on how to use the [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) ***function***. Begin there.

Comment: Also, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And lastly, you do know that backslashes inside strings in C++ are *special* and have a special meaning? If you want a path either escape them (with another backslash) or use forward slashes (`/`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But have no how to open image with createProcess

Comment: You're using the wrong API to open an image *file*. I suggest you read about [launching applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886(v=vs.85).aspx). There are also thousands of examples of this all over. Use your favorite search engine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want to display the image using paint 
But *Without* ShellExecute

Comment: So your question is, where does paint live?

Comment: *Why?* What is the reason to use the easiest solution (`ShellExecute`)? Why do you want to complicate things? What is the *real* problem you want to solve? Just do *display* an image, or to allow users to *edit* it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Using forward slashes limits you to 260 characters for path names. Using forward slashes is not the answer to any question.

Comment: ...and forward slashes are not supported everywhere. Backslash is the true path separator on Windows, using anything else is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to open an existing image using defualt app then use [ShellExectue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) API. For example:

```
ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", L"Z:\\cat.PNG", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

You could also open image with mspaint using the same API:

```
ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\mspaint.exe", L"Z:\\cat.PNG", NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

ShellExecuteEx will let you wait for finishing process.

You can do the same using [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx). As @DavidHeffernan pointed out the second parameter of [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) should point to writable memory else it will raise access violation. To make it clear I will just omit the first parameter. Example:

```
STARTUPINFOW process_startup_info{ 0 };
process_startup_info.cb = sizeof(process_startup_info); // setup size of strcture in bytes

PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info{ 0 };

wchar_t commandline_args[] = L"\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\mspaint.exe\" Z:\\cat.PNG";

if (CreateProcessW(NULL, commandline_args, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &process_startup_info, &process_info))
{
    //WaitForSingleObject(process_info.hProcess, INFINITE); // uncomment to wait till process finish
    CloseHandle(process_info.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(process_info.hThread);
}
```

**I strongly recommend to read [this CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1842/A-newbie-s-elementary-guide-to-spawning-processes) (A newbie's elementary guide to spawning processes).**

Comment: This is such a poor answer. CreateProcess is no use for the task described in the question. Even if it was, passing a literal ad the second argument is sure to fail. ShellExecuteEx will allow you to wait on the new process. But there won't be a new process so that's no use either.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I should say ShellExecute is a better option. I said it will allow to wait process to finish. The question is not precise. However, I thought that it would be good to present the working code of CreateProcess (as OP posted code with CreateProcess). You said "But there won't be a new process so that's no use either." - could you explain that part?

Comment: Your CreateProcess code does not work. I explained why. When you open an image through the shell, no new process is created.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right. The second parameter of this function is INOUT and should point to writable memory because CreatProcess CAN modify this string. That's the reason why I provided the first parameter. It wont raise access violation exception (or it should not because Im not 100% sure it wont in all cases but that is what im doin if I need to check something in hurry). Anyw, I agree with you, there should be pointer to writable memory. Just edited my answer to make things clear.

Comment: Speaking of ShellExecuteEx.. are you trying to say that SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS mask won't do the job? I just checked the code from CodeProject article. It does work as intended.

Comment: For opening images you typically won't get a process handle

Comment: Your edit doesn't help. Now you've got a mix between wide L literals and TCHAR. Time to give up this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `CreateProcess` function can only start .exe and .bat files. Use [`ShellExecute[Ex]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) if you want to [launch files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886(v=vs.85).aspx) the same way the shell/Explorer does.

A process must have a PE EXE file as its main file and if you ask `CreateProcess` to start something else it is just going to fail. `ShellExecute` will look up the file extension in the registry to find the correct executable (or COM handler) to execute and this often ends up calling `CreateProcess` on your behalf with the file you specified as a command line parameter.

Using `ShellExecuteEx` with the `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` flag **might** might give you a process handle you can wait on but you also have to be prepared for `hProcess` being NULL. This can happen if the registered application for the file type is already running and DDE or COM was used to open the file in this existing application instance...